# Captcha Code questions regarding iMacros

Tags: javascript, extract, captcha, imacros

So I've Googled up a few links on how to auto type in Captcha Codes using iMacros.

Here are the following links I've tried:

- http://www.beatcaptchas.com/imacroscode.html
- http://karmaproject.co.uk/how-to-solve-captcha-with-deathbycaptcha-in-imacros/

Both of them did not work the problem is that I'm getting after I open a new tab it takes me to [this link](http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher). Then what happens is it says "-1".

So when I go to the `extract` part, it doesn't do anything and in the end, it doesn't enter the code.

So here are my questions:

- How exactly does the extracting work?
- Is it possible if I can manually save my own Captcha codes? There aren't a lot of them in the website I'm playing/using. How would I get to extract them properly if that was the case?

Answer (score -1):

you are using wrong captcha submission link. 
here is correct one:
http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher?function=picture2&print_format=html
in this link you need to insert your deathbycaptcha username and password, select saved captcha image and click send.
if submission is ok you will get responce with result which you can scrape from the page.

Comment: So wait, I need to sign up and pay for deathbycaptcha? Because I edited the `URL GOTO=` part but I'm still getting a -1 on it.

Comment: yes you need to have account on deathbycaptcha and pay for captchas